# Pushing to a webserver from BitBucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

In my current setup I have a local repository that I work on and make changes to code, and then push these changes to a remote repository on a server at Bitbucket.org.

At the moment, when the changes are all pushed to the remote repository, I then take what's on my local machine and use FileZilla to upload this to a web server.

This approach kind of undermines the use of Git as I could still accidentally upload the wrong file or something.

Is there a way in which BitBucket itself can push the repository to the server as a form of deployment? As this would enable me to just push and pull using Git without factoring in deployment to the server manually.

Comment: you can install git on the server and pull the repo to it every time you want a deployment, what tool do you use for provisioning the web server?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to approach this.

1. Configure a [webhook](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/manage-webhooks-735643732.html) on your server to pull and update a local copy of the repo, and provide Bitbucket with the details.
2. Use [Bitbucket Pipelines](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/build-test-and-deploy-with-pipelines-792496469.html) to push the content.